# Return polymorphic type with data member

Tags: go, polymorphism

I'm trying to write a function `getTargetServer()` to return a polymorphic type that has both a data member `URL` and a method `Close()`.  This would be a generalization of the [`*Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server) returned from [`httptest.NewServer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewServer) but I want to alternatively be able to return a custom type for which `Close()` is a NOP.

```
type externalTestServer struct {
    URL string
}

func (externalTestServer) Close() {}

func getTargetServer() *externalTestServer {
    if urlbase, ok := optionals["urlbase"].(string); ok {
        return &externalTestServer{URL: urlbase}
    } else {
        testServer := httptest.NewServer(newMyServerHandler())
        // return testServer // ### Error ###
        return &externalTestServer{URL: testServer.URL}
    }
}

func Test_health_check(t *testing.T) {
    testServer := getTargetServer()
    defer testServer.Close()
    response, err := http.Get(testServer.URL + "/health")
    assert.NilError(t, err)
    assert.Assert(t, cmp.Equal(response.StatusCode, http.StatusOK))
}
```

This works like a charm except that `Close()` is *always* a NOP.  When I uncomment the indicated `### Error ###` line in order to return a closable `*Server`, I get the following error message:

> cannot use testServer (type *httptest.Server) as type *externalTestServer in return argument

I understand the error, but haven't discovered a solution that lets me return a polymorphic type that generalizes `*Server`

---

Note: "A Tour of Go" defines an *interface type* as follows:

> An *interface type* is defined as a set of method signatures.

Therefore, returning a simple interface will not allow for directly-accessible data members.

Comment: The only form of polymorphism in Go is interfaces, and interfaces describe only behavior; they cannot have fields.

Comment: [reddit: interface vs struct with the function pointers](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/7vaw7o/interface_vs_struct_with_the_function_pointers/)

Comment: -2: At this rate, I'll never become "Inquisitive" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a struct that has a field which is a string `URL` and a field that is a `Close` `func`. The `Close` `func` can be implemented by either `externalTestServer` or `httptest.Server`:

```
type server struct {
    URL   string
    Close func()
}
```

```
    if urlbase, ok := optionals["urlbase"].(string); ok {
        extServer := &externalTestServer{URL: urlbase}
        return &server{
            URL:   urlbase,
            Close: extServer.Close,
        }
    }
    testServer := httptest.NewServer(newMyServerHandler())
    return &server{
        URL:   testServer.URL,
        Close: testServer.Close,
    }
```

Comment: This seems to behave exactly as I had hoped -- and very simple to construct.

Comment: Don't even need `externalTestServer` -- can just use `Close: func() {}` to create the NOP.

Answer (score 2):

http.Server is a struct, so you cannot return a polymorphic object that generalizes that. You can do something else though:

```
type Server interface {
  GetURL() string
  Close() error
}

type testServer struct {
   URL string
}

func (t testServer) Close() error {}
func (t testServer) GetURL() string {return t.URL}

type httpServer struct {
    *http.Server
}

func (t httpServer) GetURL() string { return the url }
```

You can then return Server from your function.

Comment: Nice answer.  This is similar to the approach that I initially thought I would have to take.  It's kind of bulky (creating extra wrappers for things) though, so not my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Drew's approach is ideal for this specific case, because it requires minimal code overhead.  Put another way, it is the simplest thing that will solve today's problem.  The solution uses the magic of an implicit closure (for the *receiver*) to reference the implementation of `Close()` polymorphically.

My slightly simplified version of that is here...

```
type genericServer struct {
    URL   string // snapshot of internal data
    Close func() // single-function polymorphism without 'interface'
}

func getTargetServer() genericServer {
    if urlbase, ok := optionals["urlbase"].(string); ok {
        return genericServer{URL: urlbase, Close: func() {}}
    }
    testServer := httptest.NewServer(newMyServerHandler())
    return genericServer{URL: testServer.URL, Close: testServer.Close}
}
```

---

By *embedding* an actual *interface type* into to return struct, this concept can be seamlessly extended to better support non-trivial polymorphic interfaces.  In this case, the Polymorphism is explicit based on the internal use of an interface type.  Still, the returned type is a wrapper that includes a copy of the (constant) member data, so the usage is identical -- effectively generalizing that of [`*Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server) for this use-case.

```
type Server interface {
    Close()
}

type nopServer struct {
}

func (nopServer) Close() {}

type genericServer struct {
    URL string // snapshot of specific data
    Server // embedded interface type for explicit polymorphism
}

func getTargetServer() genericServer {
    if urlbase, ok := optionals["urlbase"].(string); ok {
        return genericServer{URL: urlbase, Server: nopServer{}}
    }
    testServer := httptest.NewServer(newMyServerHandler())
    return genericServer{URL: testServer.URL, Server: testServer}
}
```

---

Note that the `URL` value is not a live member of the implementation, so these solutions, as presented, are only meaningful when the data value will not change, although perhaps that limitation could be overcome by using a pointer.